# Why is my scraping script printing the first item multiple times before working properly?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Beginner here, trying to learn web scraping and Python in general.

I've been working on a spider after watching a few tutorials on basic web scraping to scrape the product names ("special_offers"), and urls on this website: https://m.alibaba.com/sitemap/showroom/showroom-A.html.
The code is as follows:

```
import scrapy

class SpecialOffersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "special_offers"
    allowed_domains = ["m.alibaba.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://m.alibaba.com/sitemap/showroom/showroom-A.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath("//ul[@class='link-container']/li"):
            yield{
                'title': product.xpath(".//li/a/text()").get(),
                'url': response.urljoin(product.xpath(".//li/a/@href").get())
            }
```

The spider works with no errors on debugging, but I only get Null results for the titles, and the urls are all wrong.

I've tried changing up the xpath modifiers (like removing the ., starting with //a), but I haven't been able to produce any correct outputs.

Comment: for selecting a tag from another tag like your problem you need to use ./ at the beginning to select nearest tag for you when you using .xpath() on another tag and for None title is because there is li tag with seprator class and doesnt have any content in it so you have to filter that out.

Comment: first turn off `JavaScript` in web browser and see what you get on this page in web browser. Many pages use `JavaScript` to add elements but `scarpy` doesn't run `JavaScript`. It may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) (and extension scapy-seleniu`) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

Comment: some portals have complex system to detect spamers/hackers/scrapers and they may block access to real HTML. You should check `response.page_source` to see what HTML you get from server. Maybe there will be some information/warning or captcha to check if you are real human (not bot) - and it may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to get around it. But portals may have also system to detect `Selenium` and block access.

Comment: I didn't test it but I think I see problem - first you search `.../li` and later you search `.//li/a/...` - so you have too many `li` - you search `li` inside `li`. Second should be `.//a/...` instead of `.//li/a/...`

Answer (score 0):

First you search `.../li` and later you search `.//li/a/...` which gives `../li//li/a/...`- so you have too many `li`. You search `li` inside `li` and this makes problem.

Inside loop you should search `.//a/...` instead of `.//li/a/...`

---

I found other problem - there are empty `li` to create space between other elements - and it may need one of three methods

- check if `title` is not `None`
- get only `li` which have `a` - like `.../li[a]`
- get `../li/a` and later directly `.//text()`, `.//@href`

---

I add code which searchs button `Next` to load next page because there is another problem. `class` in this button has space at the end. For `scrapy` this space is very important - it treats string with spaceas and with many classes as single class (but in `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` you would use class without this space and many classes as separated classes)

---

Full working code - using `.../li[a]`.

You can put all code in one file `script.py` and run `python script.py` without creating project.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy

class SpecialOffersSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "special_offers"
    
    allowed_domains = ["m.alibaba.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://m.alibaba.com/sitemap/showroom/showroom-A.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath("//ul[@class='link-container']/li[a]"):
            yield {
                'title': product.xpath(".//a/text()").get(),
                'url': response.urljoin(product.xpath(".//a/@href").get())
            }

        # find button `Next` tp get url to next page
        # warning: this button has class with space at the end 
        
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='btn-pagination-next ']/@href").get()
        print(f'NEXT PAGE: {next_page}')
        
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page)  # it sends `Request` with url to next page         
            
# --- run without creating project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})

c.crawl(SpecialOffersSpider)
c.start()
```

Version using `.../li/a`

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath("//ul[@class='link-container']/li/a"): 
            yield {
                'title': product.xpath(".//text()").get(),
                'url': response.urljoin(product.xpath(".//@href").get())
            }
```

---

**EDIT:**

you can use `list comprehension` to generate list `start_urls`

```
class SpecialOffersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = [f"m.alibaba.com/sitemap/showroom/showroom-A_{x}.html" for x in range(1,4)]
```

You can also add two lists to create one list with urls.

```
class SpecialOffersSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    start_urls = ["m.alibaba.com/sitemap/showroom/showroom-A.html"] + [f"m.alibaba.com/sitemap/showroom/showroom-A_{x}.html" for x in range(1,4)]
```

Eventually you can use function `start_requests()` to generate list with requests - it allows to add extra parameters to `Request` (ie. use `SeleniumRequest` or add `dont_follow=False` or send extra paramater in `meta=...`

```
class SpecialOffersSpider(scrapy.Spider):


    def start_requests(self):
        requests = [scrapy.Request("m.alibaba.com/sitemap/showroom/showroom-A.html")]

        for x in range(1,4):
            requests.append(
                scrapy.Request(f"m.alibaba.com/sitemap/showroom/showroom-A_{x}.html")
            )

        return requests
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been working at this code for a while now trying to scrape just 3 pages, and trying to save the output as a txt file. Could you help me out? 

    x = 0
    while x < 4:
        x = x + 1
        start_urls = ["https://m.alibaba.com/sitemap/showroom/showroom-A_" + str(x) + ".html"]
       
I put this in between allowed domains and def parse. I have no clue about saving as text file though.

Comment: if you use `'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},` or run (as project) with option `-o output.csv` then it writes `yielded` results in file CSV (and this is text file) and you don't have to write it on your own. Shorter is use `for`-loop: to generate list with urls `start_urls = [f"m.alibaba.com/sitemap/showroom/showroom-A_{x}.html" for x in range(1,4)]` but I would rather check if page has link to next page and run `parse` with next url. `yield Request(link_to_next_page)` - this way it will scrape all pages (not only 4 pages). In example I use `yield response.follow(next_page)` for this

Comment: if you need more complex list with urls then you can add lists - ie. `start_urls = [some_url] + [ ... for x in range(1,4)]` or you can create function [start_requests()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=start_urls#scrapy.Spider.start_requests) to generate `start_urls`